# Will universities accept my application if IELTS score not arrive before deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, language-exams

I will get my IELTS result on 25th November. My test centre told me, if I electronically send my IELTS score to my university, it generally takes around 10 business days. Now, even if I send my test score on 25th November, there is a chance my score may not arrive within the deadline 15th December. In that case, will my university process my application without an IELTS score? Thanks.

Comment: Ishrat-- does IELTS give that 10 business day guarantee in writing? Also, it looks to me like there are more than 10 business days between Nov 25th and Dec 15th. How many are you calculating?

Comment: Is this for Masters, PhD? What country? At my institution in the UK, if you met the other admission requirements you would probably be given a conditional offer subject to meeting the language requirements (assuming they made a decision before you provided the test scores). Mileage on this could vary depending on institution, programme, etc.

Answer (score 4):

While we can't say for certain, it is very probable that you will be fine. Universities probably don't begin evaluation immediately on the due date. If everything else is on time, then I wouldn't be too concerned. Moreover, evaluation takes a while.

You might want to inform any university about the fact that you've taken the exam and the results are pending.

Moreover, if your application materials show a good grasp of the language there won't be a lot of worry.